# Catch all taxonomy template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

I've created a custom taxonomy and I'm trying to get Wordpress to display the taxonomy template when no term is defined. Currently Wordpress is only showing the template when a term is defined on the URL.

My taxonomy is called `projects` and defined like this:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => "Categories",
        'singular_name' => "Category",
        'search_items' => "Search Categories",
        'popular_items' => "Popular Categories",
        'all_items' => "All Categories",
        'parent_item' => "Parent Category",
        'parent_item_colon' => "Parent Category:",
        'edit_item' => "Edit Category",
        'update_item' => "Update Category",
        'add_new_item' => "Add New Category",
        'new_item_name' => "New Category Name",
    ),
    'hierarchical' => TRUE,
    'label' => 'Categories',
    'query_var' => TRUE,
    'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'projects'
    ),
);

register_taxonomy('projects', 'project', $args);
```

Next to this I have created a template file called `taxonomy-projects.php`.

Currently when I browse to the `http://mysite.com/projects` URL, Wordpress falls back to the `index.php`. How can I make it so that when no term is defined, Wordpress shows my `taxonomy-projects.php` template?

**UPDATE**:

I should have added this straight away, I'm clearing my rewrite rules each time I make a change to try again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I ended up using the archives.php and had a little more luck with that. It would see and use the archives.php (and the archives-video.php I created from it), but would not see taxonomy.php or taxonomy-videos.php or category.php like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flushing your rewrite rules?

If not, go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks`, and click "save" (no need to make any changes), to force WordPress to flush the rewrite rules.

Comment: Sorry. Yes. I know about resetting the rewrite rules. I do this every time I make a change. No luck.